# where have example of context switching

Tags: c, pthreads

assume function pointer pointed to A is passed to pthread_create
and after the thread run, i change the address of function pointer to static function B from A

I do not understand how one thread switch bwetween two functions A and B with push and pop 
as i would like to save the context of function A when interrupt the thread of it

any example to show this context switching

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking here... but I'll give it a shot.

To address your first paragraph, I think what you're asking is what will happen when you pass a function pointer (which points to function `A()`) to `pthread_create()`, then modify the function pointer to point to a different function (function `B()`). The answer is that modifying the function pointer has no effect on the running thread; since you passed a copy of the function pointer to `pthread_create()`, the running thread will not detect that you modify your function pointer later on.

I believe you're really after something else, though: How is a thread context switch implemented? Let's assume for the moment that you're doing cooperative multitasking, i.e. a running thread explicitly needs to yield the CPU by calling a `yield()` function. Here's pseudocode for what a simple yield function might look like; we'll call the currently running thread "thread A" and the thread to which we're switching "thread B":

```
void yield()
{
    Save all registers to the stack
    Save current stack pointer in some data structure dedicated to thread A
    Choose a different thread to yield to (in our case, this is thread B)
    Change stack pointer to the stack pointer that was saved for thread B
    Restore registers
}
```

That's right, a thread context switch, in essence, simply means switching the stack pointer to a different stack. The key effect of this is that the return address on the stack is now no longer the one that was put on the stack when thread A called `yield()`; instead, the return address is the one that thread B put on the stack the last time *it* called `yield()`. So when `yield()` returns, it returns to wherever thread B was the last time it yielded control of the CPU.

Pretty funky, huh? It takes a moment to get your head wrapped round it.

If you want to extend this cooperative multitasking to preemptive multitasking, then all you have to do in principle is create an interrupt that gets called at regular intervals by a timer; the interrupt service routine for this interrupt is simply `yield()`.

Real implementations have a lot more details to take care of, but in principle, this is all there is to thread context switches -- it really just means switching stacks.

Comment: if changing stack pointer can determine which function i run, does it mean that i do not need pthread, and without the limit of number of infinite loop functions running?

Comment: @william: To create threads, you should definitely use your OS's threading API -- e.g. pthreads. Don't try to switch stack pointers yourself -- it doesn't give you any advantages over using the official API, and you _will_ get into trouble. I was merely trying to paint a simple picture of how threading might be implemented in an OS, since I thought that was what you were asking. I'm afraid I don't understand your comment about the infinite loops -- can you clarify?

Comment: a function has a while(true) {} loop if all threads are occupied by these infinite loop such as server non blocking listening loop.

Comment: actually i want a server to accept and treat more connection from the requests of client and afraid that the limit number of threading not enough to satisfy.

Comment: @william: If you've got a server that is running non-blocking (i.e. polling) loops, you're going to run into problems sooner or later. If at all possible, you should find some way of making your loops blocking.